# What does it mean when a function is unsafe

Tags: c#

I am calling this function in my code:

```
[Register ("setCheckable", "(Z)V", "GetSetCheckable_ZHandler")]
public unsafe virtual void SetCheckable (bool checkable);
```

Can someone explain what it means when its declaration says "unsafe"?

Comment: How about google it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe

Comment: I can see where it explains it but can't understand what it means :-(. Would it suggest that there could be a problem in me calling it at any time?

Comment: This article (which is linked to at the bottom of the one David gave you) explains the concept of "unsafe" code in much more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code . Basically it's all about the way it accesses and uses memory

Comment: Microsoft developed c# to prevent blue screen crashes.  Most blue screens were caused by accessing data outside of the limits of the program or the execution stack getting corrupted.  So Managed code add a lot of protections to prevent the computer from crashing. Unamanged code is simply old fashion code that doesn't have added protection to minimize computer crashes.